# Calculate the Average Based on Date in a Column in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the average values based on the date in a column. With the option to select the number of previous days for example, 4 days. Get the average of the previous 4 records minus the StartDate and roll the average down until there is an EndDate.

I was trying the

```
tapply(df$Boe, df$ShutinDate, function(x) mean(tail(sort(x), 5)))
```

function but I’m not getting the correct average.

Output

```
Name    DATE    Values  StartDate   EndDate    Average
TestA   3/3/2017    50          
TestA   3/4/2017    75          
TestA   3/5/2017    25          
TestA   3/6/2017    100         
TestA   3/7/2017    100         
TestA   3/8/2017    50          
TestA   3/9/2017    80          
TestA   3/10/2017   90          
TestA   3/11/2017   25             3/11/2017        
TestA   3/12/2017   0                           80
TestA   3/13/2017   0                           80
TestA   3/14/2017   0                           80
TestA   3/15/2017   0                           80
TestA   3/16/2017   50      3/16/2017
```

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` so we can reproduce your data and attempt solutions. Providing an sample of the desired output would also be good.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We group by Name (assuming `rollapply` should be done separately for each `Name`) and then use `width = list(-seq(4))` with `rollapply` which uses offsets -1, -2, -3, -4 for each application of `mean`.  (Offset 0 would be the current point but we want the 4 prior here.)

Not clear what you are referring to regarding start time so that part has been left out.  Also I have assumed that the data is sorted (which is the case in the question).  You might also want to convert the dates to `"Date"` class but that isn't needed to answer the question if the rows are already sorted.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, list(-seq(4)), mean, fill = NA)
transform(DF, Average = ave(Values, Name, FUN = roll))
```

**2)** or if you like dplyr then using `roll` from above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   mutate(Average = roll(Values)) %>% 
   ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that I look at this answer. I've studied part 2) but haven't been able to apply it to my situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023898/compute-a-rolling-weighted-sum-by-group

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `zoo::rollapply` along with `dplyr::lag` as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

df %>% mutate(DATE = mdy(DATE)) %>%   #Convert to Date
  arrange(Name, DATE) %>%             #Order on Name and DATE
  mutate(Avg = rollapply(Values, 4, mean, fill= NA, align = "right")) %>%
  mutate(Average = lag(Avg)) %>%      # This shows mean for previous 4 rows
  select(-Avg)
#     Name       DATE Values Average
# 1  TestA 2017-03-03     50      NA
# 2  TestA 2017-03-04     75      NA
# 3  TestA 2017-03-05     25      NA
# 4  TestA 2017-03-06    100      NA
# 5  TestA 2017-03-07    100   62.50
# 6  TestA 2017-03-08     50   75.00
# 7  TestA 2017-03-09     80   68.75
# 8  TestA 2017-03-10     90   82.50
# 9  TestA 2017-03-11     25   80.00
# 10 TestA 2017-03-12      0   61.25
# 11 TestA 2017-03-13      0   48.75
# 12 TestA 2017-03-14      0   28.75
# 13 TestA 2017-03-15      0    6.25
# 14 TestA 2017-03-16     50    0.00
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Name    DATE    Values  
TestA   '3/3/2017'    50          
TestA   '3/4/2017'    75          
TestA   '3/5/2017'    25          
TestA   '3/6/2017'    100         
TestA   '3/7/2017'    100         
TestA   '3/8/2017'    50          
TestA   '3/9/2017'    80          
TestA   '3/10/2017'   90          
TestA   '3/11/2017'   25  
TestA   '3/12/2017'   0   
TestA   '3/13/2017'   0   
TestA   '3/14/2017'   0   
TestA   '3/15/2017'   0   
TestA   '3/16/2017'   50",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```