# How to caclulate moving average for proportional data using zoo package (rollmean)

Tags: r, moving-average, proportions, geom-area

I have the sample dataframe as below,

[image]

Where for each date the total 'value' score is 1 as the 'varible' is proportion. Now how can I calculate the zoo:rollmean for 'value' based on dates considering 'variable'?

In the end I need to make areaplot using all mean variable values according to date as below.

[image]

I have tried group_by(variable) but it did not give the desired output

Thank you!
Wasim

Comment: Does the following answer inspire you https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382902/8806649?

Comment: Please read the information on asking questions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  Note in particular that input should be provided in an easily reproducible form as the output of `dput` since no one wants to retype data in images.  Also show the code attempt and the expected output.